How many times query will be sent and executed in a database with non-materialized parameters?
I am sorry if this question is silly, but I am eager to know the answer.
We are using linq2db. I believe that this IQueryable will be executed one time in the database. But I am not sure whether it is true because of Resharper warning
which says Possible Multiple enumeration.
My linq2db query looks like this:
IEnumerable ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(x => {Console.WriteLine(x); return x;});

IQueryable<PersonDto> query =
    from person in dbContext.GetTable<DbPerson>()           
    where ids.Contains(person.Id)  // here warning `Possible Multiple enumeration`
        || ids.Contains(person.DepartmentId) // here warning `Possible Multiple
                                             //  enumeration`
    select
        new PersonDto
        {
            Name = person.Name,
            Id = person.Id,
            DepartmentId = person.DepartmentId
        }).Distinct();

await query.ToListAsync()
            

I know that it can be easily fixed by calling .ToList(). But I just want to know whether it is true that query  will be sent to database 20 times? (because of Enumerable.Range(1, 10) and ids is used twice in where condition)

What do you mean by non-materialized parameters? Materialization refers to whether a view's (or query's) results are already precalculated and stored. If the concern is about the enumeration warnings, don't use a raw IEnumerable<> and definitely not just IEnumerable. You gain nothing except bugs. Just use var ids=Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray();.

Contains uses the list items to construct an ID IN (@id1, @id2,...) clause.

@DavidG I'm not sure providers can do anything. ids isn't an expression so the provider has no idea what ids contains. It only sees an opaque IEnumerable. In order to cache the results of the first iteration it would have to not only identify it's the same object (eg with reference equality) but also assume it won't produce different results. Which isn't a safe assumption. The code could return GUIDs for example

@downvoter what is the reason to downvote? I would be glad to know what can be improved in my question. Thank you.

Yes, query will be executed only once. But ids wll be enumerated at least two times during query execution. LINQ translator needs this for two Contains translation.

First, Linq2DB isn't related to EF Core, it's an entirely different ORM.
Second, There won't be multiple executions. The Resharper warning doesn't refer to multiple SQL query executions at all, it refers to multiple iterations of the ids IEnumerable and is correct.
Just use this instead:
var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();

or
var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();

non-materialized parameters isn't an EF, Linq2DB or SQL concept. EF Core or Linq2DB providers convert the IEnumerable<T>.Contains(someProp) clause to the SQL condition prop in (@value1, @value2, ....). When that happens the provider has to iterate over all the values. While that costs nothing with a list or array, it forces re-evaluation of any enumerables.
You gain nothing by using an IEnumerable<T>, much less a typeless IEnumerable. You may even cause extra boxing as the generated integers are boxed into objects.
In EF you can get the generated SQL if you use the ToQueryString, eg:
var sql=query.ToQueryString();

In Linq2DB I think you can just use ToString() but I haven't found a reference yet. So try this to see what you get:
var sql=query.ToString();


That's what I said. And I'm 100000% sure Linq2DB would do the same

The warning refers to multiple iterations of the ids IEnumerable. That warning is correct

I repeat that multiple times. Too many. Besides, I seriously doubt any provider could do anything other than iterate multiple times. ids is an opaque IEnumerable object, not an expression, and could return different values every time, eg GUIDs.

thank you for your response! I upvoted!  Am I  correctly understood about the following two points: 1) SQL query will be executed only once in database 2) and 10 times will be executed ids while creating where statement?

The query will only run once and ids will be iterated 2 times. That's how many times it's used.

@Learner why are you using such code? That's far more code than the usual var ids=Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray(). Is this the real query or are you trying to somehow use a list or eg 1000 client-provided IDs ?

thank you for your replies! I really appreciate your answers! Is this the real query or are you trying to somehow use a list or eg 1000 client-provided IDs ?  - I use this query to understand how it works

master, could you see, please, this question

Pana already answered the point about ids being iterareted twice ("The Resharper warning doesn't refer to multiple SQL query executions at all, it refers to multiple iterations of the ids IEnumerable"). So this second question is pointless.

In general when R# informs you about that warning, that means that you're iterating the same collection of items multple times. This might be okay sometimes, e.g. when your collection already is materialized into an array or a List<T>. However when your collection is an IQueryable<T>, you're performing the query again whenever you call IEnumerator.MoveNext() - which is done implictely e.g. by calling First, or foreach on said queryable.
In your case the warning comes from IEnumerable ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10) .Select(x => {Console.WriteLine(x); return x;});, which isn't a materialized collection. So best would be to call ToArray or ToList on it and the warning disappears.
On the other side as that collection is pretty small and doesn't depend on any external (potentially heavy) dependencies, you can ignore the warning.
Btw.: I hope your ids-variable is just for testing purposes. You should generally avoid linq-expressions that have side-effects like Console.WriteLine. While it works, it somehow contradicts the purpose of LINQ which is about querying, not about modifiying. Better use a classig loop in these cases.

thank you for your response! Am I right that SQL query will be executed just one time?
